# How to handle ungrouped but related data in XSLT and produce grouped output?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an **XSLT *2.0*** script, that takes an (poorly designed) XML input document and should produced a more handable XML output document.

The input document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>
        <subelement id="1_1">1.1</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="1_2">1.2</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="1_foo">1.foo</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="1_bar">1.bar</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="2_1">2.1</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="2_2">2.2</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="2_foo">2.foo</subelement>
    </element>
    <element>
        <subelement id="2_bar">2.bar</subelement>
    </element>
</root>
```

There is some business logic to apply, in order to identify the related subelements:
Take the `id` of the `subelement` and the part left of the underscore (`_`) is the data record id, while the right part is the field id.

The wanted XML output of the XSLT process should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <record id="1">
        <field id="1">1.1</field>
        <field id="2">1.2</field>
        <field id="foo">1.foo</field>
        <field id="bar">1.bar</field>
    </record>
    <record id="2">
        <field id="1">2.1</field>
        <field id="2">2.2</field>
        <field id="foo">2.foo</field>
        <field id="bar">2.bar</field>
    </record>
</root>
```

This is a very basic example, but it illustrates the task acceptably.

**Important**: The order of the input document is random.

When possible, the transformation should be happen in one single transformation.

**How to approach this task?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info or any other introduction to grouping in XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I could only find discussions about XSLT grouping when there is a "constant" across the ungrouped records (either single element with attributes, or multiple elements with a constant element at the beginning). I have nothing of those scenarios.
My problem lie in the constant is a *part* of an attribute and not the whole attribute.

Comment: Panic ye not, all you need to do is something like `<xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-by="substring-before(subelement/@id, '_')">`

Comment: @burnersk, well, "Take the id of the subelement and the part left of the underscore (_)" is something basic XPath skills allow you to solve without understanding any XSLT grouping so I assumed that part would not pose a problem but Tim has shown you how to integrate that within grouping.

Comment: I asumed that the grouping expression must be a "constant" and cannot be computed (besides using a whole attribute value).

Comment: @burnersk, the article I linked to links to the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group and that should tell you the details instead of assuming them (`group-by? = expression`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this: using for for-each-group**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-by="substring-before(subelement/@id, '_')">
                <record>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <field id="{substring-after(subelement/@id, '_')}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                    </field>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </record>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```